# SpringMVC w/ Maven - not able to get Servlet to find second page

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to build a demonstrator example for a Spring MVC project that uses DispatcherServlet, following a precedent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2b-NbR48Jo&t=551s

It has been straightforward, up until I tried to add a second JSP file to the project and the program is not able to access it after initiating the main page successfully. Briefly, this project takes two numbers in the "index.jsp" file and then returns a plain text message in the "display.jsp" file, in advance of building an addition ability into the Controller...

I am also using Apache 10.0.2 for this and Spring Tools Suite 4.10.0.RELEASE with Eclipse.

[image: Page 1 asking for inputs]

This is the code for making the above image in the index.jsp file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="add">

    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The display.jsp file simply is this, generated by Eclipse, and this is the file my program can't seem to find:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3c//DD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html14/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    I'm here

</body>
</html>
```

The web.xml file that initiates the DispatcherServlet and sets the URL pattern is also standard issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The telusko-servlet.xml file has the expected content to facilitate annotation use in the controller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">

   <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
   <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.telusko"></ctx:component-scan>

</beans>
```

The AddController.java file:

```
package com.telusko;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

//will be responsible for adding two numbers

@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add()
    {
        return "display.jsp";
    }
}
```

POM file dependencies, but i don't think these connect to the issue:
[image]

Last thing, project structure:

[image]

The error I get after clicking the "Submit" button on the first page is this:
[image]

It is generally clear that Apache cannot find the page, but I cannot understand fully why. I've tried a number of resolutions to resolve the problem:

1. Eclipse is using the Tomcat installation in the server settings
2. The location is also set to Servers/Tomcat v10.0 at localhost.server
3. Tried changing the URL pattern to "/*", "/Dispatcher/*", to no avail, and left it back with just the forward slash
4. Deleted the "target" folder in the Maven file and let it recreate
5. Corrected header references in the XML file (i.e. adding a missed "/schema/")
6. Updated/cleaned Maven project and server, separately. It leads to a separate error :
   [image]

And this error is solved with adding `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` under the  set of tags, at which point it reverts to the original 404 error.

7. I am using later version of JAR files, but I'm not sure if it might be a compatibility issue with STS4 and the version in the project.
8. Running the "display.jsp" file on its own does make it show with the "I'm here" message.
9. Targeted Runtimes for the project is set to Apache Tomcat v10.0.

I am exploring other possible angles on this problem, but it has proven to be persistent. Thank you in advance for your insight!

Comment: Spring doesn't support Tomcat 10 as that is an implementation of JakarteEE not JavaEE. Downgrade to Tomcat 9 or don't use Spring.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on that fact - I downgraded to Tomcat 9, but still nothing. In this case, I have to use Spring for the purpose too...

Comment: You might still get nothing but that should be another error... If not you are still deploying to Tomcat10.